# How to count number of instances in a db that have both characterics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

An organization can have multiple members, and a member belongs to exactly one organization. A member can be an admin or not.

An admin member should only be able to be deleted if an organization has 2 admin members or more. This I would like to achieve through an if statement.

How can Ruby count the number of members for an organization that have the admin characteristic? I now have:

```
<% if (member.admin && @organization.members.admin.count < 2) %>
```

This produces the error message:

```
undefined method 'admin'
```

It is the second part after the `&&` that doesn't work. If I remove that part it produces no errors.

Given that `@organization.members.count` is something that calculates the number of members for an organization, I thought `@organization.members.admin.count` might calculate the number of members of that organization with admin=true. This is apparantly incorrect. But then how *should* I count that number of members?

Comment: post the DB schema for the members table, or explain to us how admin is defined in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an admin scope to your `Member` model:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :admin, -> { where(admin: true) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, after adding that to the model Ruby can indeed execute `@organization.members.admin.count `